# Python: Can't get hold of real process ID with subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, vim

I'm developing a python script which fires up the MacVim editor to edit one o more text files and does some parallel processing while the file is open. I need to check for the file being still opened or already closed for the processing to stop. Also it is required to track every single file, since files can be opened and closed independently.

I am creating threads for every file. Obviously I don't want my script to open several instances of MacVim, so I am implementing a Vim Server in order to open tabs inside a single window.

```
from threading import Thread

class CtrlThread (Thread):        
    def __init__(self, editfile):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.editfile = editfile

     def run (self):
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/mvim", "-g", "--remote-tab-silent",self.editfile])
```

Later on I create the thread:

```
 tr = CtrlThread(editfile)
 tr.start()
```

**I came across a weird behavior of MacVim.**
There are at least two different ways to start it. One is via `/usr/bin/mvim`, the other using the path `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim`. When I use the first path, MacVim behaves correctly concerning the server (no extra windows, no multiple instances) but the `subprocess.call` doesn't wait for the file to be closed. Instead, it jumps out of the run() right away.

Using the second path, the `call` method waits for the file to be closed and exits the run() after that nicely. The downside is that it messes up the vim server completely (useless windows, multiple instances of MacVim). 
I tried opening the vim server (MacVim --servername SERVER) before sending new files to it with `--remote ...` but that doesn't change anything.

So I tried to track the pid of the process, but neither `call` nor `Popen` gives me the correct pid for the file, instead it returns the pid for some higher Vim instance:

```
 def run (self):     
    p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/mvim", "-g", "--remote-tab-silent" ,self.editfile])
    print("Pid: ", p.pid)
```

Output:

```
Pid: 1699
```

Shell output (ps aux):

```
USER  PID   ...  COMMAND
user 1699   ...  (Vim)
user 1702   ...  /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -f -g -g --remote-tab-silent /path/to/file
```

In case I can't find another way than tracking the pid I would need the second pid in any case but I can't find a way to get hold of it.